# nodejs connector to mariadb keeps timeouting

Tags: javascript, node.js, mariadb, raspberry-pi4, mariadb-10.4

This is my first stackoverflow post, I am currently working on a project for school, but unfortunately I can't get this bug fixed.

I have a node.js script which should process a JSON file and insert it into a MariaDB database. However, when I execute the script, the following error message appears after 10 seconds (timeout). I suspect that it is not due to the processing function of the script, but already timed out before.

The database and the script are both on my Raspberry PI 4 with Rasbian

Regards
Alex from Frankfurt, Germany

Error message:

```
Error:  SqlError: (conn=-1, no: 45028, SQLState: HY000) retrieve connection from pool timeout after 10002ms
    (pool connections: active=0 idle=0 limit=5)
    at module.exports.createError (/home/alexpi/node_modules/mariadb/lib/misc/errors.js:64:10)
    at Pool._requestTimeoutHandler (/home/alexpi/node_modules/mariadb/lib/pool.js:349:26)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
  sqlMessage: 'retrieve connection from pool timeout after 10002ms\n' +
    '    (pool connections: active=0 idle=0 limit=5)',
  sql: null,
  fatal: false,
  errno: 45028,
  sqlState: 'HY000',
  code: 'ER_GET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'
}
```

node.js script:

```
const mariadb = require('mariadb');
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
const fs = require('fs');

// Read the JSON file
const rawData = fs.readFileSync('weather.json');
const weatherData = JSON.parse(rawData);

// Database connection configuration
const pool = mariadb.createPool({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'query',
  password: 'query_pw',
  database: 'weather',
  connectionLimit: 5,
});

async function processData() {
  // Create a connection
  let conn;
  try {
    conn = await pool.getConnection();

    // Delete existing entries in the database
    await conn.query('DELETE FROM allData');

    // Iterate over each weather entry
    for (const entry of weatherData.weather) {
      // Parse and convert timestamp to CET
      const timestampCET = moment(entry.timestamp).tz('Europe/Berlin');

      // Round values
      const temperature = Math.round(entry.temperature);
      const windSpeed = Math.round(entry.wind_speed);
      const precipitation = Math.round(entry.precipitation);
      const precipitationProbability = Math.round(entry.precipitation_probability);

      // Insert data into the database
      await conn.query(
        'INSERT INTO allData (date, time, temperature, wind_speed, precipitation, precipitation_probability, icon) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
        [
          timestampCET.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
          timestampCET.format('HH:mm:ss'),
          temperature,
          windSpeed,
          precipitation,
          precipitationProbability,
          entry.icon,
        ]
      );
    }

    console.log('Data inserted successfully.');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error: ', err);
  } finally {
    if (conn) conn.release(); // release connection
  }
}

// Process the data
processData();
```

When I type "netstat -tunlp", I get the following output:

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State                                                                                                                                      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                                                                                                                     -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                                                                                                                     -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                                                                                                                     -
tcp6       0      0 :::1883                 :::*                    LISTEN                                                                                                                                     -
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN                                                                                                                                     -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN                                                                                                                                     -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42112           0.0.0.0:*                                                                                                                                                          -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                                                                                                                                                          -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                                                                                                                                                          -
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                                                                                                                                               -
udp6       0      0 fe80::fed7:dfaa:a02:546 :::*                                                                                                                                                               -
udp6       0      0 :::42625                :::*                                                                                                                                                               -
```

When I use a simple script without a connection pool I get a different error message:

```
Error fetching data: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1481:16)
 From event:
    at /home/alexpi/node_modules/mariadb/lib/connection.js:138:13
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Connection.connect (/home/alexpi/node_modules/mariadb/lib/connection.js:1                                                                                                                               27:12)
    at Object.createConnection (/home/alexpi/node_modules/mariadb/promise.js:38:                                                                                                                               17)
    at fetchDataFromDatabase (/home/alexpi/weather/testdirect.js:14:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/alexpi/weather/testdirect.js:25:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '::1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true,
  sqlState: 'HY000'
}
```

I have read through every Google entry on the error message and asked AI, but unfortunately no approach has worked so far.

Comment: Can you type in the command "netstat -tunlp" and add the output to the question ?

Comment: Connection timeout usually means that your nodejs script could not connect to your local mariadb server, try these first, make sure you can actually connect to your mariadb server in your machine using a dbeaver or a different database client, if can not, try to make sure mariadb is running first, I am assuming here that you already have setuped mariadb locally in your machine first.

Comment: @RedaBourial I've added the output of 'netstat -tunlp' to the question

Comment: Does it work without connection pooling?

Comment: The output of netstat seems to indicate that mariadb is running and listening, which is weird because a timeout usually indicates that mariadb isn't running. can you try connecting to mariadb from the cli : "mysql -u query  -p" and tell us if the db is working ?

Comment: @madflow I've tested it with a simple select script. It still crashes, but I get a different error message. I've added the new error message to the question

Comment: @RedaBourial I actually I can't login with the querry user, but I've created a 'test' user, which I granted all privileges. With this 'test' user and with my root user I can login normaly into the mariadb

Comment: did you try your code with the "test" and root users ?

Comment: @RedaBourial yes multiple times, different codes with every user, always the same error
It's the first time I'm using mariadb, are there settings I should change or is there maybe a raspberry internal firewall which is blocking the requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message "ECONNREFUSED ::1:3306" suggests that it's trying to connect via IPv6, while mariadb is listening only in ipv4 (from the netstat output).

Try changing the code to force an ipv4 connection :

```
// Database connection configuration
const pool = mariadb.createPool({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  user: 'query',
  password: 'query_pw',
  database: 'weather',
  connectionLimit: 5,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Reda's answer is technically correct, however, I'd like to suggest an alternative approach: configuring MariaDB to listen on both IPv4 and IPv6. This method offers a more seamless integration with future applications, as it allows the use of the hostname 'localhost' without the need to specify IP addresses.

Moreover, adopting IPv6 is in line with current best practices and future-proofs your setup. Operating services in dual-stack mode ensures compatibility with both IPv4 and IPv6 connections. It's also important for us as professionals to become increasingly familiar with IPv6 and its benefits.

To implement this, you need to add an additional bind-address entry to your MariaDB configuration file, which is typically located at either /etc/mysql/my.cnf or /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf. Simply add the following line after the existing bind-address line:

```
bind-address = ::1
```